# Prove that $\sum_\limits{k=1}^{\infty }\left(\frac{1}{k}-\frac{1}{k+2}\right) = \frac{3}{2} $

Tags: sequences-and-series

$$
\mbox{Can't get it, can you explain it for me:}\qquad
\sum_{k=1}^\infty \left( \frac{1}{k}-\frac{1}{k+2}\right) = \frac{3}{2}
$$

Comment: This makes no sense as for $k=2$ the summand is undefined. Otherwise, this is a telescope sum (or two intertwined telescope sums)

Comment: Do you mean $k+2$ by any chance?

Comment: yep, you r right it is k+2, let me edit

Comment: @DavidQuinn : that's what I was thinking. Otherwise the typical term would be negative, putting aside the problem of the first couple of terms as written

Comment: Just write the terms out and see how they cancel

Comment: Further Pure 2?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming the sum is in fact
$$
\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{k}-\frac{1}{k+2}
$$
Then we have
$$
\sum_{k=1}^{N}\frac{1}{k}-\frac{1}{k+2}=\\
(1-\frac{1}{3})+(\frac{1}{2}-\frac{1}{4})+....+(\frac{1}{N}-\frac{1}{N+2})\\
=1+\frac{1}{2}-\frac{1}{N+1}-\frac{1}{N+2}\rightarrow 3/2
$$
as $N\rightarrow \infty$

Answer (score 2):

Notice that $$\sum_{k=1}^\infty \frac{1}{k}-\frac{1}{k+2} = \left(1-\color{#034da3}{1\over3}\right) +\left({1\over2} - \color{orange}{1\over4}\right) + \left(\color{#034da3}{1\over3} - \color{purple}{1\over5}\right) + \left(\color{orange}{1\over4} - {1\over6}\right) + \left(\color{purple}{1\over5} - {1\over7}\right) + \cdots$$
As we keep going out further, nothing will cancel out the $1$ and the ${1\over2}$ terms. Everything else will cancel with a step three fractions out. Hence we get $$\sum_{k=1}^\infty \frac{1}{k}-\frac{1}{k+2} = 1 + {1\over2} = {3\over2}$$

Comment: The conclusion is correct, but you should be more careful with manipulations like that...

Comment: Use `\color{choose_color}{stuff_in_color}` to beautify such illustrations.